# vim map y,c,d text objects into registers?

Tags: vim

How do I map y,d,c so that I can copy into a text object into registers y,d,c ?

I want to ciw, and it copies inner word into register "c

Tried this already , don't work.

```
map c "cc
map c "c
```

Work around (don't want to do this):

```
map <leader>ci "cci
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No recursive mapping is going to help you:

```
nnoremap c "cc
nnoremap y "yy
nnoremap d "dd
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it ! :)  I did that but now I cant delete lines with , dd, or copy an entire line with yy ?? Is there a hack I have to do for this ? After doing this I'm not able to do dd, yy

Comment: @ritchie add similar no-re mappings `dd -> "ddd`, `yy -> "yyy`...  I won't recommend all those mappings anyway.

Comment: Thanks that's what I needed , can't believe I forgot about that noremap